# ElementsByClassName rules on Id

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am wanting to iterate over some DiV's by class name, and only show the one which has the correct ID while hiding all the other DIV's of the class.

Should be simple enough, but can't find other examples.

HTML

```
<div class="buttonBox">
    <input type="button" value="Veiw Profile" onclick="showSlides(\'settings\')"></input>
</div>

...

<div class="slide" id="home" style="display: inline;">
    <p>Home Page</p>
</div>
<div class="slide" id="settings">
    <p>Profile Settings</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function showSlide(s) {
   var i;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (x[i].id == s){
          x[i].style.display = "inline";
      } else {
          x[i].style.display = "none";      
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT: Purpose
What I am trying to have is a series of slides which make up a large portion of the body of the page. When a variety of inputs are utilized, such as buttons or field submission (such as search function). The showSlide function (thanks to those who highlighted the spelling error) will hide all other slides and display the corresponding slide.
The desired result is that the slide area on the page will quickly switch between different content.

Comment: This should kinda work. What's happening?

Comment: you've got a typo in the function name: `showSlides` vs `showSlide`. Also I'm not sure why you're escaping the single quotes in the `onclick` attribute, there's no need for this (and I don't know if what you have there will even work, although it might). Main issue as I said is the different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch in the function name used in the HTML and in JavaScript. Also remove the escape character around the parameter:

```js
function showSlides(s) {
   var i;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (x[i].id == s){
          x[i].style.display = "inline";
      } else {
          x[i].style.display = "none";      
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonBox">
    <input type="button" value="Veiw Profile" onclick="showSlides('settings')" />
</div>

<div class="slide" id="home" style="display: inline;">
    <p>Home Page</p>
</div>
<div class="slide" id="settings">
    <p>Profile Settings</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of if else , you can use `document.querySelectorAll` and `:not`selector.

In this example it will select all div with class `slide` except the one which have `id` as required.

Then add `hide` in the class list.

Also remember for this you have remove inline style, which has got higher precedence

```js
function showSlides(s) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.slide:not(#' + s + ')').forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.add('hide')
  })
 }
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonBox">
  <input type="button" value="Veiw Profile" onclick="showSlides('settings')" />
</div>
<div class="slide" id="home">
  <p>Home Page</p>
</div>
<div class="slide" id="settings">
  <p>Profile Settings</p>
</div>
```